# Blade - different random numbers for custom directive

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using `Laravel Framework 6.20.12` and `PHP 7.4.1`.

I have created a custom blade directive:

```
        $blade->directive('randomValFromArr', function ($expression) {
            return '<?php $array=' . $expression . '; $val = array_rand($array, 1); echo $array[$val]; ?>';
        });
```

This directive basically, chooses a random value from an array of values and outputs it.

If I use this 2 times in my `*.blade.php` file I get for both functions the same array output or in other words the same key:

```
@randomValFromArr(["1", "2", "3", "4"])

@randomValFromArr(["1", "2", "3", "4"])

{{--
OUTPUT:

1
1
--}
```

It seems to me that the blade engine computes the directive once and then uses it within the template.

Any suggestions how to really get a random value or unique value for each occurrence of my `@randomValFromArr`-functionm like:

```
@randomValFromArr(["1", "2", "3", "4"])

@randomValFromArr(["1", "2", "3", "4"])

{{--
OUTPUT:

3
1
--}
```

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: One approach could perhaps be storing the array in the user's session after removing the randomly generated value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blade will compute the directive each time it is called; otherwise, how could we pass in parameters, what if you passed in different arrays?

I tested your code and it worked as expected.